# Problem using custom Arabic font on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, fonts, xamarin.ios

I'm developing an iPhone application with MonoTouch that uses a custom Arabic font (Scheherazade from http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&id=ArabicFonts). I don't have problems getting the font loaded in my application. I also see that it is used when I use Latin text but when I want to display Arabic text it uses a default system font for displaying the text.

Does anyone have any experience with custom Arabic fonts and MonoTouch/iPhone development or has an idea why this is happening?

Thank you in advance.

With kindest regards,

Taner Gedikoglu

Comment: If you don't figure this out, there's always special characters. Cmd+Alt+T

Comment: Usually a self-contained test case, or a code snippet showing the problem is useful to pinpoint what you might be missing.

Comment: Agreed with miguel.de.icaza. How are you drawing your text?

Answer (score 7):

These classes will do the job :

https://github.com/Accorpa/Arabic-Converter-From-and-To-Arabic-Presentation-Forms-B

Download them, and I'm pretty sure that answers your question because I had the exact same problem before!

An example of the code :

```
ArabicConverter *converter = [[ArabicConverter alloc] init];
NSString* convertedString = [converter convertArabic:@"منذ دقيقة"];
infoText.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"YOUARABICFONT" size:16];
infoText.text = convertedString;
```

Comment: Using the same class but on textView it fails while we input text via keyboard. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

If you're targeting iOS 6, you can use `NSAttributedString` to achieve this a lot more simply:

```
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:info.text attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Scheherazade" size:32], NSLigatureAttributeName: @2}];

cell.textLabel.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17309179/2358334) for some discussions on other matters commonly relevant to arabic fonts such as line-spacing and ligatures.

Answer (score -1):

The API you use to show the text could be the issue you're facing. Look at this question (and answer): [no german umlaute in CGBitmapContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201193/no-german-umlaute-in-cgbitmapcontext)