# Custom Arabic Font is working in iOS7 but not in iOS6

Tags: ios

I have a custom arabic font `.ttf` file. I have followed all the processes like load font with .plist file and I am ensuring that font is loading. But it is not applying in **iOS 6**. When I switch to **iOS** 7 it works perfectly.

Please help me what is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it didn't work in iOS6 and before, this seems it was a bug, there are some tricks you can do, check below SO questions:

[Problem using custom Arabic font on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6823084/problem-using-custom-arabic-font-on-iphone)

[Custom Arabic font in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691567/custom-arabic-font-in-ios?rq=1)

[Custom font in a storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9090745/custom-font-in-a-storyboard)

Comment: I had a bad time trying to do that, finally it works fine in iOS7 :D.