# CoreGraphics - Special characters not drawn correctly

Tags: macos, encoding, character-encoding, xamarin.ios, core-graphics

I am drawing an image using CoreGraphics and can't get the €-sign displaying correctly..

The dollar sign works fine, however. I have tried it using different fonts but same problem, my guess now is that there is an encoding problem of some sort, but I still cant get it working correctly.

Here is my code that does the drawing:

```
context.SelectFont (font.FamilyName, font.PointSize, CGTextEncoding.MacRoman);
context.SetFillColorWithColor (color.CGColor);
context.SetTextDrawingMode (CGTextDrawingMode.Fill);
context.SetShouldAntialias (antiAlias);
context.ShowTextAtPoint (position.X, position.Y,text);
```

Anything that can point me in the right direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "euro" sign is a bit [more recent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Latin_character_sets_%28computing%29#The_euro_sign) than other characters but, even if defined in MacRoman, I could not get CoreGraphics to display it properly with ShowTextAtPoint (I suspect an encoding issue).

However it works fine if you use UIKit instead of CoreGraphics, see Q&A:
[no german umlaute in CGBitmapContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6201193/no-german-umlaute-in-cgbitmapcontext) for the sample code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, worked like a charm after I converted my PointF-coordinates using context.ScaleCTM (1f, -1f);